# Ajax loading data from a different file

Tags: html, css, ajax

Can someone tell me why this is not working

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#driver").ready(function(event){
    $('#stage').load('index.php');
  }); 
});
</script>
```

What I have on the index.php is a table with link, the problem is that is really hard to click on one of those link, I have to click like 10 times to make it to work, any ideas why?

Index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stage').load('index.php');
});
</script>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name </td>
    <td>URL Address</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.google.com/">Googe</a></td> 
    <td><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

I include the same function on my index.php, the idea is if a make a change on the index page,  and reflect the change on the test page.

Comment: try using class instead of id

Comment: I guess your index.php have some scripts such as jQuery and other JS files. So when you load them in to the DOM, your page may freeze for some time.

Comment: Remove the second `ready(function)`

Comment: Thanks, I remove the second line of ready(function) but i still had the same problem, is hard to make a link to work

Comment: What happens if you remove the load call from index.php?

Comment: works fine, but my idea is to have multiple two browsers open at the same time(chrome, firefox) and change something in my index.php and automatically see those change on every browser open, the way the code is now works, but the links are hard to click

Answer (score 2):

The `ready` event is only triggered on the document, remove the `$("#driver").ready(` part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stage').load('index.php');
});
```

Comment: Thanks I try this, but I had the same result hard to click on one of the links

Comment: @CarlosPerez post the html for index.php.

Comment: check my post update, and thank you for trying to helpme