# jquery function to load data from a different file

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why if I use this function two times in the same page is hard to click on the links that are in index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stage').load('index.php');
});
</script>
```

Comment: what did you mean with "hard to click"?

Comment: Do you mean to load content to the same element twice?

Comment: @MaiKaY Im trying to load the data into the same page, I say that is hard because you have to click like 10 times to make the link work

Comment: @CarlosPerez in this case you need event delegation.

Comment: @sideroxylon Yes that pretty much what im trying to do, my idea is to have a page with this function, that will load the data that is in index.php, and have the same function in 'index.php' so the same function in two file

Comment: Have you tried without the function being repeated in index.php, to see if the links work with just a  simple load?

Comment: @sideroxylon you mean just having one time the function

Comment: yes - just in the page which has `#stage`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax loading data from a different file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898027/ajax-loading-data-from-a-different-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `.load()` is used for a more dynamic purpose, like drawing a specific element from index.php like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( '#stage' ).load( 'index.php #content' ); // Fetch the content div in index.php
});
```

When grabbing the entire page, I would find it much more appropriate to fetch it via the `.get()` function and populating that way like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "index.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#stage" ).html( data );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation syntax for `click` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stage').load('index.php');

    $('#stage').on('click', 'a', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

---

As you are using `.load()` method to populate the `div#stage` so direct binding of event won't work here. So in this case you need to delegate the event to the closest static parent which is in this case is `#stage` div itself. Event delegation has a specific syntax:

```
$(staticparent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

In this syntax you can change this `$(staticparent)` with `$(document) or $(document.body)` as this the parent of all elements in a page so `$(document)` is always available for delegating the event to it.

Comment: if I add something like this, the user will need to click on a link to be available to see the data inside 'index.php'

Comment: @carlosPerez would you plz explain a bit more about it.

Comment: @downvoter plz comment for a downvote. As i tried to answer respective to the question asked: _Why if I use this function two times in the same page is **hard to click** on the links that are in index.php_

Comment: Thank you for this. The way Im testing that this work, is if open two browsers(chrome, firefox) and I make a change into index.php I want to reflect that change automatically into both browsers, the way is now works fine, but the link are really difficult to make to work

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iframe to show content from different file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#frame").attr("src", "index.php");
});
</script>
```